# Javascript Charting scaling multiple series

Tags: javascript, charts, jqplot

I need to display a javascript chart with up to 8 series that vary wildly in values. Some of the series will display 0-1 values, and the rest of them could be anywhere from 0-1000000.

How can I display this data simultaneously on a Javascript chart? The problem I run into with jqPlot (what I'm used to) is it will display all the series but it's impossible to tell the values that go from 0-1 apart from each other and whether they are 0 or 1 at that moment in time.

X axis will always be a datetime range.

I'm used to jqPlot but couldn't figure out a way to do it. I'm open to other javascript solutions.